# Xamarin forms custom stepper value in listview

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I have a list with a custom stepper in it, and I have a detail page for every item in this list, I need to change the value of the custom stepper when I change it in the detail page and also when I refresh the list.

This is the list of items and the info button is to go to the item detail page

[image: items]

And here is the item detail page

[image: item detail page]

How can I change it? thanks in advance

Comment: Are you listing the datas from api or local database?

Comment: Im listing it from an api

Answer (score 0):

Your data collection should implement *INotifyPropertyChanged* interface and you should call OnPropertyChanged for Quantity when you change value with stepper.

Answer (score 0):

**Solutions:**

1. What about refresh the `list` in the `onAppearing` of `listView Page`?

Every time you changed the `value` in the `item detail page` and update the latest data to the sever side. Then you go back to the `listView Page`, it will trigger `refresh` in `onAppearing` and then you can get the updated value from `API`.

2. You can use [messaging-center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center):

> when I change it in the detail page and also when I refresh the list.

Send a Messaging(`stepperChanged`) when the value changed:

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage> (this, "stepperChanged");
```

> change the value of the custom stepper

In your listView Page, Subscribe the Message named `stepperChanged`:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage> (this, "stepperChanged", (sender) => {
    // do something whenever the "stepperChanged" message is sent
    // refresh the list here
});
```